# How do I use ListProperty (Items in the numbers list must all be Key instances)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

First Model

```
    class A(db.Model):
      number = db.IntgerProperty()
```

second Model

```
class B(db.Model):
   name = db.StringProperty()
   numbers = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

`A` Model successfully saved.

```
a = A()
a.number = 90
a.put()
```

BadValueError: Items in the numbers list must all be Key instances

```
b = B()
b.name = 'test'
b.numbers = [90]
b.put()
```

Will you please help? thanks alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit (based on OP comment):  If you want to insert a `db.Key` you'll need to provide one.
Calling `put()` returns a key, so you can use that, e.g.:

```
a = A()
the_key = a.put()

b = B()
b.name = 'test'
b.numbers = [the_key]
b.put()
```

---

Old answer before OP clarification:

With `db.ListProperty(db.Key)` you're saying you want a list of `db.Key` instances.
If you want integers, declare your model like this:

```
class B(db.Model):
   name = db.StringProperty()
   numbers = db.ListProperty(int)
                             ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

a:

```
a = A()
a.number = 90
a_key = a.put() # returns the Key object of a's datastore entity
```

b:

```
b = B()
b.name = 'test'
b.numbers = [a_key] # store a Key object in the ListProperty of b
b.put()
```